# Converting from [h]:mm:ss

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet which contains the hours individual employees have worked in a month.

This column is set to a custom format `[h]:mm:ss`. I want to convert the hours worked into an integer.

I'm using this formula to try and convert the values:

```
=(HOUR(F4)*60+MINUTE(F4)*60+SECOND(F4))/60
```

Nothing is coming out as expected, though.

For `159:05:45`, I get `20.75`, for example.

Can anyone explain what's going on and how to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Hour * 60 gives you minutes
Minutes * 60 gives you seconds

And you're adding both; which immediately doesn't sound right.

If you want the time in minutes, you can do something like that:

```
=F4*24*60
```

And format as number.

Date/time is stored in days. Multiply by 24 to get in terms of hours and by 60 to get minutes.

Comment: Whichever answer has worked for you please accept is as answered

Answer (score -1):

Use  `=((TEXT(f4,"[hh]")*60)+MINUTE(f4)+(SECOND(f4)/60))`

Comment: I have updated the new formula, one extra bracket  was placed